# Is it secure to keep sensitive data in nodejs variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, websocket

I'm building a WebSocket server (let's call it **myServer**) on node.js which connects to remote wss (w/SSL) server (**remoteServer**), which needs a secret for authentication reasons (**myServer** will monitor **remoteServer** to store received data).
I don't want to hardcode this secret into **myServer**.js, instead I'll ask client to provide it on every connection (**myServer** is for one person, who connects from multiple places to see **myServer** is working and also for authorisation reasons). (bruteforce protection included)
On the very first connection to **myServer** it will try to connect to **remoteServer** with provided secret and if it's successful, **myServer** will keep the secret in a variable to compare it with future connections to **myServer**. (otherwise **myServer** will need to reconnect to **remoteServer** every time a user connects)

So, can someone get this secret from outside? (if the variable isn't global)

What should I do to secure this script better? (hash the secret for example, keep it somewhere else, etc)

Comment: The danger is more that, as long as the secret is in memory and constantly used, you can easily accidentally leak it to logs or in the output of error responses. If you use a shared secret to authenticate, you should use it only for the initial authentication, and then exchange it for an auto-expiring token.